# Error being thrown with trigger: ORA-20987: APEX - ORA-01858 ORA-06512

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have been working on a trigger that counts the number of users when the table is modified.

Tables:

```
SKN_ENJIN
ID            NUMBER
ENJIN_NAME    VARCHAR2(99)
EMAIL         VARCHAR2(99)
IP_ADDRESS    VARCHAR2(15)
STATUS        NUMBER


SKN_ENJIN_COUNT
ID            NUMBER
COUNT_DATE    DATE
MEMBER_COUNT  NUMBER
```

Trigger

```
create or replace trigger "BI_SKN_ENJIN_COUNT_TG" 
  after insert or update or delete on "SKN_ENJIN"               

  DECLARE
  mCount    NUMBER;
  mDate     DATE;

begin 

  select COUNT(ID) into mCount from SKN_ENJIN where Status = 1;

  select CURRENT_DATE into mDate from dual;

  MERGE INTO SKN_ENJIN_COUNT c
      USING (Select * from SKN_ENJIN_COUNT)
      ON (TO_DATE(c.Count_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') = TO_DATE(mDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY'))
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET c.Member_count = mCount
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (Count_date, Member_count)
      VALUES (mDate, mCount);
end;
```

When I manually place data into the Object Browser, the triggers work fine.
When I place the script into the SQL Commands, it also works...

But when I place the same data in the app, I get this error:

```
Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX - ORA-01858: a non-numeric
character was found where a numeric was expected ORA-06512: at 
"SOKAN_MEMBER_DATA.BI_SKN_ENJIN_COUNT_TG", line 11 ORA-04088: error during
execution of trigger 'SOKAN_MEMBER_DATA.BI_SKN_ENJIN_COUNT_TG' - Contact
your application administrator. Details about this incident are available
via debug id "835641798". for .
```

Comment: `mDate` is a `date` so converting it to a string and back to a date risks conversion errors. (If `skn_enjin_count.count_date` is also date, then the same applies.) Maybe your `nls_date_format` is not `'MM-DD-YYYY'` in the Apex environment. The *'non-numeric
character'* part of the error message suggests it has a month abbreviation e.g. `'DD-MON-YYYY'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to perform TO_DATE conversion on the date variables/columns. It produces the implicit converstion to varchar2 first, and then back to date.

Try simple truncation of date (the time is set to 00:00:00).

So instead of this one:

```
ON (TO_DATE(c.Count_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') = TO_DATE(mDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY'))
```

Use this:

```
ON (trunc(c.Count_date) = trunc(mDate))
```